# Pandas add new column and fill it with item from list when tuple of other 2 columns is unique

Tags: python, pandas, list, multiple-columns

I am currently trying to add some values of a list to a new column in my pandas table.
First value of `col3`is the first of the list. Second value is the same in case the tuple of `col1`and `col2`is still the same.
Condition to start adding the next item of the list is that it is a new unique combination of the items from column `col1` and `col2`.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,1,1,1,3,3,3,10], 'col2':[1,1,2,2,9,9,9,5]})

list1=[5,9,3,12]
col1 col2                     col1 col2 col3
1     1                       1     1    5 
1     1                       1     1    5
1     2       should become   1     2    9
1     2  ------------------>  1     2    9
3     9                       3     9    3
3     9                       3     9    3
3     9                       3     9    3
10    5                       10    5    12
```

I had it working with just 1 column as condition like that:

```
di =dict(zip(df['col1'].unique(),list1))
df['col2'] = df_averageInPanda['col1'].map(di)
```

To run it with the tuple condition I tried `drop_duplicate()`, as the `unique()`function does not work on multiple columns, but it does not work, but gives me an empty `col3`

```
di =dict(zip(df[['col1','col2']].drop_duplicates(),list1))
df['col3'] = df['col1'].map(di)
```

Any idea of how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shift()` and compare to initial values to analyze when values change and then `map` into your `list1` values.

```
s = df.ne(df.shift()).sum(1).cumsum()
df['col3'] = s.map(dict(zip(s.unique(), list1)))

    col1    col2    col3
0   1       1       5
1   1       1       5
2   1       2       9
3   1       2       9
4   3       9       3
5   3       9       3
6   3       9       3
7   10      5       12
```

---

*Timings for small df:*

```
df = pd.concat([df]*100).reset_index(drop=True)

%timeit s = df.ne(df.shift()).sum(1).cumsum(); df['col3'] = s.map(dict(zip(s.unique(), list1)))
2.81 ms ± 38.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.merge(df.drop_duplicates().assign(col3=list1))
3.39 ms ± 32.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Timings for big df:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

%timeit s = df.ne(df.shift()).sum(1).cumsum(); df['col3_'] = s.map(dict(zip(s.unique(), list1)))
184 ms ± 1.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df.merge(df.drop_duplicates().assign(col3=list1))
87.6 ms ± 2.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

In detail, `df.ne(df.shift()).sum(1).cumsum()` yields a series of values that are cumulatively unique

```
0    2
1    2
2    3
3    3
4    5
5    5
6    5
7    7
```

Then, you `map` these values into your `list1` values, and assign back as a column.

Comment: Works perfectly fine with the data I left here, Thank you!. Somehow with my own Data it just fills up the 5 first rows of `col3` with the 5 distinct element of the list. Do `col1` and  `col2` have to be next to each other so that it works? @RafaelC

Comment: @Mauritius don't know how you df is, but yes! Basically, instead of using `df` here, use `df[['col1', 'col2']]` where col1 and col2 are the columns you want to use as reference to groupby the values ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative method. You can use Pandas to create a new dataframe of unique rows (maintaining order) and assign a new column. Then merge this with your original dataframe:

```
res = df.merge(df.drop_duplicates().assign(col3=list1))

print(res)

   col1  col2  col3
0     1     1     5
1     1     1     5
2     1     2     9
3     1     2     9
4     3     9     3
5     3     9     3
6     3     9     3
7    10     5    12
```

Comment: from time to time I get a `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`. I am trying to find out why that is

Comment: @Mauritius, This will happen if `list1` has a different length to the number of unique values in `df['col2']`. Your question implies they must align.

Comment: This is how i create the list. What do you think?`df_average=df.groupby(['col3','col1'], as_index=False)['col2'].mean()  list1=df_average.col2.tolist()`

Comment: @Mauritius, Why are you grouping by `'col3'`? This column is *calculated* for the result, not an input. I honestly have no idea where you derive `list1` from. Your question has it as a given input.